# PuTTY compression for SSH 2

Tags: ssh, putty

I just saw that there is an option to enable “compression” in PuTTY. I know that TLS compression is not good, so I'm wondering if it's the same for SSH protocol version 2.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe the answer would likely be the same. I believe TLS and SSL operate in a relatively similar manner, with differences that wouldn't likely be different based on compression.  I notice the question alrady has one close vote as I write this, probably because the person thought the question isn't very sensible (because a better question would be, is SSH protocol version 2 considered to be good these days?).  At the time of this writing, TLS 1.3 is used and TLS 1.2 is still widely supported and there are some widestpread efforts to cease wide usage of TLS 1.1 and 1.2 and SSH3 & SSH2 & SSH1

Comment: @TOOGAM: You're confusing SSH versions and SSL versions. The SSH protocol has no relationship to SSL/TLS, and SSH v2 is still the current version.

Comment: (Overall, the question is roughly the same as "Is TLS compression bad in all cases, or is it only bad for HTTPS due to attacker-controlled JavaScript websites", which is sensible and _probably_ has been discussed somewhere on Security.SE, I think.)

Answer (score 1):

Typically the security problem with TLS and compression involves a typical web browser, or other scenario where an attacker can cause network traffic to be generated (e.g., with JavaScript).  That's because an attacker can modify other data in the connection, and determine the value of secret data, such as a cookie or other credential, based on how well the result compresses.

Whether this is a problem in SSH as well depends on what you're doing with it and whether a similar scenario can occur.  In general, for most interactive uses (e.g., working at a shell or in a text editor), compression is not very helpful, since you're sending a large number of small packets which you want to arrive quickly, and you're not going to see appreciably better changes by enabling compression.  Thus, there's no point in enabling it here.

The time compression might be useful is if you're sending large bulk data transfers where the data tends to be redundant and isn't already compressed.  This isn't very likely to fall into the same kinds of security problems as mentioned above, so it's probably okay.  However, if you have a reasonably fast network connection between the two machines, it might not make that much of a difference, and if you want to avoid any hint of a security problem, you can just not enable it.

Comment: In fact, the droplet is not that far away and the differences is not even visible.
THANKS a lot, now I understand how it works. :))